# Running a PowerShell Script .PS1

Tags: powershell

I am trying to generate a MachineKey for my application using the PowerShell script found in [kb2915218](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2915218#AppendixA).

I have copied the function into notepad and saved as a .PS1 file. Now if I look at this file through explorer it is being recognised as a PowerShell file.

I then have run PowerShell and `CD` to the directory of my .PS1 file.

I then ran the following command:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

followed by:

```
.\Powershell-Generate-MachineKey.ps1
```

(the name of my script). And finally I then tried running the command

```
Generate-MachineKey
```

However I get the message:

```
Generate-MachineKey : The term 'Generate-MachineKey' is not recognized as the
name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Generate-MachineKey
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Generate-MachineKey:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong here?

Comment: `. .\Powershell-Generate-MachineKey.ps1` (note the leading dot).

Comment: what a wally i am, I've been looking at this for about an 1hr. Great! please add this as a solution and i'll accept :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The script just defines a function, so if you execute it like this:

```
.\Powershell-Generate-MachineKey.ps1
```

it won't do anything, because the function isn't invoked anywhere and also isn't made available in the current context. For the latter you need to [dot-source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx) the script

```
. .\Powershell-Generate-MachineKey.ps1
```

The dot-operator basically executes the script in the current context instead of a child context. That way the definitions from the script become available in the current context, and you can invoke the function like this:

```
Generate-MachineKey
```